# Is there a better way to process these if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a Java application that plots graphs for min/max/avg values of an accelerometer and gyroscope in their three fields xyz. I would like to be able to plot each factor independently, i.e. maximum acceleration in the X field with the average acceleration in the Z field etc.

I have used radio buttons for min/max/avg and for acceleration/y/z and gyroscopex/y/z.

I also thought about making radio buttons for min/max/avg for each variable but then I would have 18 separate variables.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
if (selectionAccelX == 1 && selectionAccelY == 0 && selectionAccelZ == 0 && 
    selectionGyroX == 0 && selectionGyroY == 0 && selectionGyroZ == 0 && 
    selectionXAxis == 0) {

    Graphing graphing = new Graphing("Average AccelerationX");
    graphing.setAccelerationX(avgAccXSec);
    graphing.displayGraphing();
    graphing.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(graphing);
    graphing.setVisible(true);
}
```

Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: sorry forgot to include the selectionXAxis is for seconds and minutes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If these are radio buttons and they are grouped, then wouldn't selectionAccelX == 1 imply that the others (selectionAccelY and following) were all 0?

Comment: You may want the Code Review stack exchange. In any case, it's hard to say without knowing anything more about how your code is organized. Seems like you have a map of states (accel, gyro, axis, etc) to what you want to do, which means it could be shortened to a map of states => implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Your code maps one variable (the radio button selector) to another variable (the value selector).
One possible solution can be to

- add an enum (with 18 values again)
- bind every value of the enum to the return value of the radio button
- add an switch/case based on the return value to trigger the right behaviour

I assume that is not lesser code but can be more readable.